# how to use shinyFileChoose to create an reactive object to load a data.frame

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-reactivity

I've been using `fileInput` in my shiny app to upload a file and then create a reactive object that allow me to read the data.frame and do another stuff like subsetting or filtering. However, I need to get the absolute path of the file for another calculations, and it seems that `fileUpload` only stores a temporal path.

Here is the server part that works

```
 server = function(input, output) {
 options(shiny.maxRequestSize=100*1024^2)

 contents <- reactive({
     inputFile <- input$fileUpload
     if (is.null(inputFile))
     return()
     read.delim(inputFile$datapath, header = TRUE)
 })

 # Return filename as another object
 file_name <- reactive({
      inFile <- input$fileUpload
      if (is.null(inFile))
      return()
      else {  print(inFile$name); return(tools::file_path_sans_ext(inFile$name))}
  })  

output$tabla <- DT::renderDataTable({
if(is.null(contents()))
  return()
  DT::datatable(contents(), 
              filter = 'top')
})
```

However, I would like to use the `shinyFiles` option because it stores the real path, and I will need that path to load more files 
I have tries this part of code in the server to mimic the same behaviour that `fileUpload` but it does not work

```
server = function(input, output, session) {

volumes = getVolumes()
volumes <- c(Home = fs::path_home(), "R Installation" = R.home(), getVolumes()())

file_selected <- reactive({
   shinyFileChoose(input, "file", roots = volumes, session = session)
   return(parseFilePaths(volumes, input$file))
})

contents <- reactive({
  if (is.null(file_selected()))
  return()
  read.delim(file_selected(), header = TRUE)
})

# Reactive function creating the DT output object
 output$tabla <- DT::renderDataTable({
  if(is.null(contents()))
   return()
   DT::datatable(contents(), 
              filter = 'top')
 })
```

I got an error about `file` must be a character string or connection and if I use `read.delim(as.character(file_selected()), header = TRUE)` then the error is about invalid "description" argument

Comment: Can you share your UI as well? What does `getVolumes()` function do? It would be better if you provide a full reproducible code. You can edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are different possible causes of the error. Try the following steps:

- Use `req(input$file)` before parsing the file paths
- Check if `input$file` is `NULL` before parsing the file paths
- Return `$datapath` of the `parseFilePaths` function.

According to this, your code should look like the following:

```
file_selected <- reactive({
   shinyFileChoose(input, "file", roots = volumes, session = session)
   req(input$file)
   if (is.null(input$file))
      return(NULL)    
   return(parseFilePaths(volumes, input$file)$datapath)
})
```

Hope it works for you.

Comment: it works but when I hit the button to upload the file an: `invalid 'description' argument` red error shows up until the file is selected, is there any way to remove this?

Comment: What is the version of the `DT` package? Have you tried to update it?

Comment: Can you also print the output of `contents()` and tell me what is it?

Comment: `DT` version 0.5 and the outptut of contents is a data.frame of 40,000 rows and 100 columns

Comment: Have you tried writing it like `read.delim(file_selected()[1], header = TRUE)`

Comment: This message appears when you are using a vector rather than a single value. So check your other variables to see whether they return a vector of values.

Comment: this is the output of `file_selected`: `"/Users/jfertaj/Dropbox/FUNDACION/Exomas/1810661/1810661.variants.tab.gz"`

Comment: So, looks like your file is `.gz` file, right? Did you try `read.delim(gzfile(file_selected()), header = TRUE)`

Comment: No, I didn't, at the end I just use tags to remove the warnings because rest of the app looks good, I don't know if it is a common practice or know, but it does the trick

Comment: Exactly, because I also noticed that you could read the dataframe correctly, but that message was really annoying!